# How to display a certain section of an image?

Tags: html, css, image, render, crop

I am currently working on a rails app, to ease the process of events I host within the game of Minecraft. For those of you who don't know, in Minecraft multiplayer, everyone has a skin. This is what their player looks like, and it is a simple `*.png` file. The face of a player is always in a certain position in the skin; by that I mean in certain pixel coordinates.

Players' skins are hosted online, so, for example, to access my skin (lachy2901), I would go to `http://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/lachy2901.png`. Using this, I can access and embed any particular player's skin in my webpage. The problem is, I only want to display the face, after making it a little larger.

My question is; is it possible for me to get this skin file, "crop" it to a certain size and location, and then render this, without changing the original image, which I can't do, or having to store my own versions?

Thank you very much for your time and help, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Place the image inside a div with set height and with and `overflow: hidden; position: relative'; then absolutely position the image.

Comment: @Alxandr How would this work with scaling? Have CSS scale the image first, and then size of the div relative to the new size of the image?

Comment: Well, in practice you can achieve just about anything with this technique (like scaling, cropping and stretching to more advanced stuff like rounded corners). If you want to scale the image, simply scale the image (css with and height on the img tag), and then you just change the viewport (div) to whatever size makes you see the "correct" part of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See the Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nawazhi/XtAbY/)

HTML

```
<div>
<img src="https://www.example.com/logo.png">
</div>​
```

CSS

```
div{
width: 100px;
/*height:100px; specify height also if needed*/
overflow: hidden;
border: solid 1px;
}
img{
position: relative;
top: 20px;
left: -20px;
}
```

​